# inject managedObjectContext into initial viewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, uistoryboard, uimanageddocument

I am setting up a Core Data model (`UIManagedDocument`) in my AppDelegate and was curious about how I might inject a reference to the `NSManagedObjectContext` into my (storyboards) Initial viewController.

I could access it directly in the viewControllers `viewDidLoad` using [`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sampleDatabase] managedObjectContext]` and then pass it onto further controllers using `prepareForSegue`.

I was just wondering if there is an initial segue (or mechanism) that would allow me to pass (or inject) the managedObjectContext into that initial viewController without having to access it using the appDelegates shared instance once inside the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a storyboard, the initial view controller is set as the `rootViewController` property of your delegate just before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called.

You should be able to use a cast on that reference to set a property, assuming your Core Data structure is set up by then.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would just have a property on the view controller that is a NSManagedObjectContext and just set that property right after you initialize the viewController in your appDelegate. **myViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext**